# Dagger 2: Is it recommended to use a static provider for Activities and fragments?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I recently watched  [a talk by Gregory Kick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwjXqRlEevg&t=307s) on Dagger 2. There he explained about static provider methods, which could help in performance. So I was modifying all the provider methods in my project to `static`. But I have a doubt here. In my project, there are some providers which return an activity instance (an external dependency). So I have written `module`
with a constructor, which takes the `Activity` from outside.

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {
  private static BaseActivity mActivity;

  public ActivityModule(BaseActivity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
  }

  @ActivityScope
  @Provides
  Activity mActivity() {
    return mActivity;
  }

  @ActivityScope
  @Provides
  BaseActivity baseActivity() {
    return mActivity;
  }
}
```

So ,  If I have to make the providers static it would look something like as follows

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {
  private static BaseActivity mActivity;

  public ActivityModule(BaseActivity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
  }

  @ActivityScoped
  @Provides
  static Activity mActivity() {
    return mActivity;
  }

  @ActivityScoped
  @Provides
  static BaseActivity baseActivity() {
    return mActivity;
  }
}
```

So, here I'm keeping the activity instance in a `static` member. Will it cause any memory leaks? Or does dagger manage it automatically by removing the static reference whenever the activity gets destroyed? 
Keeping static providers are recommended in this case?

Comment: Yup memory leak galore

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So, only in this case, I should avoid static providers??

Comment: Well unless you reset that field to null in `onDestroy()`, yeah

Comment: What about returning a new fragment instance from a static provider?

Comment: `@Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    static MyFragment provideFragment() {
        return MyFragment.createInstance();
    }`

Comment: Is it safe to use?

Comment: That definitely won't work well after process death and will return null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it recommended to use a static provider for Activities and fragments?

**No.** All you do is create a source for errors and memory leaks. As a rule of thumb, never put any Android Framework types into static variables. They reference a `context` and you will leak memory.

As mentioned, static methods might provide a performance boost and of course you can use that. The problem with the code you show is the static method that returns a static variable—which also kind of defeats the purpose of calling the module constructor.

If you have a module that only consists of static methods you might gain some additional performance and remove the need of the module instance allocation, as they mention in the linked talk.

Static methods by themselves are okay, but they should not interact with other parts of your app, like read from or write static variables. If you have dependencies on other objects, always add them as parameters to your provides-method. That way Dagger can properly use those methods and you might gain some performance.

> What about returning a new fragment instance from a static provider?
>
> ```
> @Provides @ActivityScoped static MyFragment provideFragment() {
>   return MyFragment.createInstance();
> }
> ```

I believe this could actually be okay. It's a static method that returns a new instance of a Fragment and should not contain any side effects.

Make sure, though, that you re-create your `@ActivityScoped` component whenever the Activity gets recreated and that the Fragment does *not* retain its state. You really want to avoid that the FragmentManager manages a different Fragment from the one in your component or, even worse, both.

Comment: Thorough and correct AFAIK, as long as you're comfortable with the reference to your `@ActivityScoped` Fragment living as long as your Activity does. If you have a long-lived Activity and a heavy Fragment, you might not want your Fragment to be `@ActivityScoped` so that the GC can collect your Fragment when it's no longer showing.

Comment: Nice answer +1 but I usually just tell people not to provide Fragments as there is such a great risk of getting something wrong if they use FragmentManager

Comment: So basically, I can make use of static providers for all the providers of my Application wide component, except  Activity, Fragment, Context or such framework component? Using static providers for app wide components like Retrofit, Gson, Util classes would be safe correct?

Comment: @Jrd You can use static providers for all of your components with utils, gson, and co. Just don't provide Android framework parts from them, as a rule of thumb. So yes, that would be safe